# New symbol for an exact sequence

Tags: group-theory, notation, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

A sequence $A\to B \to C$ is exact if $\operatorname{im} f = \ker g$, where $ f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$.

Why is there not a symbol to denote such a sequence?
Which one would you suggest?

Comment: What is f? What is g?

Comment: also please consider using MathJax

Comment: See edit. Thanks

Comment: Because nobody thought it necessary.

Comment: I just write $(ex)$ at the beginning/end of the exact row/column..

Comment: I prefer using the words "is exact" after the diagram.  Or "the exact sequence" before the diagram.

Comment: I’ve said it before, but language is wonderful. You don’t have to symbolize everything under the sun.

Answer (score 2):

@egreg's comment is totally right — because there's no need in such symbol.

Also, there are at least two reasons to not introduce it. First one is that heavily symbolized mathematical writing is usually unreadable. Second is high probability of  ambiguity in case when diagram is somewhat complicated.

So I would suggest to just write «this sequence is exact at $B$», or that «pair of morphisms $f, g$ is exact» (which is better, in my opinion).

Comment: "...heavily symbolized mathematical writing is usually unreadable."  I would upvote this a dozen times if I could.

Comment: Not to rant, but I HATE seeing arguments written out in logical symbols.  "Oh, the proof is clear.  Just note that $\neg((\nexists x \in P \forall y \in Z \ni x \notin W(\alpha) \vee y) \Rightarrow (J \Leftrightarrow K \wedge Q)$."

Answer (score -2):

Here are three ideas. I prefer the last one.

[image]

Comment: These seem to indicate more about the individual maps themselves and not the sequence as a whole.  At least one is ambiguous (what if we have zigzags?) and the others are already in use for different things.